# Intuition behid $P(A\mid B)$.

Tags: probability, statistics

What is the intuition behind the formula $$P(A\mid B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$$
I have seen this formula around, but every site/book I look at does not really have a clear & cut explanation behind this formula.

Comment: Doesn't hurt to read the wiki page: [Interpretations.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes'_theorem#Interpretations)

Comment: Also, take note that initially you had written $\dfrac{P(A\color{red}{\cup} B)}{P(B)}$ but it is meant to be $\dfrac{P(A\color{blue}{\cap}B)}{P(B)}$.  I took the liberty of correcting it in your post.  The earlier has the possibility of being greater than one (*in fact it will always be if $A\setminus B$ is an event of non-zero probability*) which fails to satisfy the (*standard*) definition that probability is always between zero and one.

Comment: Rearrange it to $P(A\cap B)=P(B)P(A\mid B)$.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine a venn diagram, with two circles, labelled $A$ and $B$. The quantity within each shaded region represents a Probability of an Event. Say, if you were to shade the $A$ entirely then this would give you $P(A)$. Now,let the common region be denoted by $P(A \cap B)$. Considering your question, you want the probability $P(A|B)$, which is the probability of $A$ occurring given that $B$ has already happened. Now think about it in terms of the Venn Diagram. The only region where $B$ and $A$ events can occur is in the overlapping region, therefore you get a numerator $P(A \cap B)$ as your favorable outcome. But this time, the total number of outcome is all of $A$ therefore $P(A)$ is in the denominator.

Answer (score 0):

It's equivalent to $$\frac{n(A\cap{B})}{n(B)}$$ in other words the proportion of the members of set $B$ which are also members of set $A$.

Answer (score 0):

All probabilities are the number of desired outcomes divided by the total possible outcomes.

So P(A|B) is the number ways A and B occur divided by the number B can occur.

In other words: #A&B / #B.

This is equal to (#A&B / #everything)(#everything / #B)

Which is the RHS.

Although I prefer to think of it simply that the LHS refers to probability of A given the limited range that B occurs as well, which reasonably should be the probability that A and B both occurring in the "big" world but then reduced to the requirement that B occured.  Which is pretty intuitive to me.

Comment: Strictly speaking this is only true when the underlying $P$ is the uniform distribution on a finite set. Still, this is essentially the intuition even in more general situations.